# Download PDF file from a Directory Listing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have used a Gridview Control to display the contents of a directory in asp.net webforms.

The contents are filtered to display only PDF files.

I also have a Button inside a TemplateField. On the click of the button the user should be able to download and save the PDF file.

The columns displayed in the Gridview are File Name, Modified Date and Size.

How can I program the Button click to download and save the PDF file?

Comment: please post your gridview markup and file saved location

Answer (score 0):

I have a function that performs a file download.

```
public static void DownloadFile(string FilePath, System.Web.HttpResponse response)
{
    System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(FilePath);
    if ((file.Exists))
    {
        response.Clear();
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
        response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
        response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
        response.End();
        response.Close();
        file = null;
    }
}
```

The `FilePath` parameter is the physical path, so if you have the virtual path (e.g. `~/Folder/file.pdf`) might need to use the `Server.MapPath(...)` function to call the function.

Comment: How do I get the filename from the Gridview ?

Comment: I used this article from Scott as my starting point. http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/090110-1.aspx

Comment: Can you post the code of the GridView and the relative code behind? Without those, it is not easy to answer..

Answer (score 0):

In your `Button` click event, write the following code.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf"; 
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Your_Pdf_File.pdf"); 
    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Files/Your_Pdf_File.pdf"));
    Response.End(); 
}
```